# Which Java IDEs allow project sharing across computers (via dropbox or a flash drive)?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, project, share

I am new to Java with only a few months experience, and I am looking for a good Java IDE which allows for easy project sharing across multiple computers. I am currently using Eclipse Kepler on both Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7, and the projects are located in my Dropbox.

I find the way Eclipse manages the 'workspace' rather annoying and cumbersome in that I must delete and re-import the project every time I want to load it on the other computer, and in addition this has caused problems in the past.

I was wondering if there is another Java IDE which maintains the projects on the disk in a much more simple and portable way. Something that manages projects similar to how Code::Blocks does would be great, as there is no computer specific data included in the project file, and thus it can very easily be shared across multiple computers.

Thank you very much for your time,
Ryan Shanks

Comment: That's a pretty bad idea. You shouldn't do that. Use a version control system like Git or SVN to store your project instead. Also, the eclipse workspace is just the place where eclipse stores preferences, caches, etc. If you persist in sharing a project, then just share that: the project. You can place the project anywahere you want, not necessarily in the eclipse workspace.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Eclipse and everything to do with you not using proper version control and code sharing systems. For example, set up a Git or SVN repository (or whatever your choice is) and use e.g. Subclipse plugin for SVN for Eclipse. Now all developers can share the project, and you can import it from anywhere. NetBeans also support all common version control systems. Additionally, even if an IDE doesn't support it, you can always just commit the source tree to the repository. Do not use DropBox to share projects.

Comment: From my (personal) experience, you should focus on mechanisms that means that your locked into a single IDE, this allows developers to use the tools they are comfortable and familiar with. Things like Maven for example, which makes less assumptions about the IDE project format and standardises it allowing people to use the tools they like. Back it up with something like GIR or Mercurial for distributed CVS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a directory inside your main project folder that contains all the source code while the IDE 'project' files lie in the root folder.  Just share the sub-folder via Dropbox, not the root one.  This way each computer has its own instance of the project files.

Of course, as others have suggested, a real source code control system (repo) will make your life far better.  The above scenario is accomplished by having the source code control 'ignore' the IDE project files (and any other junk files you don't want to share).

Most IDE's are aware of and designed to use a repo, so its pretty seamless.

Answer (score 0):

To share your projects do not use Dropbox. You need a Control Version System. Try git:

http://git-scm.com/

Take some hours to learn how it works. It's worth trying.

Another thing is that you can try to use NetBeans. It supports git. You do not need to use command line.

Comment: Adding to this: For Eclipse, use [EGit](https://www.eclipse.org/egit/) ([download](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/download/), or I believe you can just search for it in the Marketplace menu).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will look into git. I was under the impression git is more for bigger projects with plans for long term maintenance, and perhaps I should have specified, I am only using Java for school, and thus the projects tend to be quite small and numerous, with a final draft and no further revisions. Would git still be suitable?

Comment: Yes, it would. Learn how to use git as quick as possible. You will use it in the market for sure.